# Why is this looping in Rust so slow?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust, as in this is the first code I've written. I'm trying to do some benchmarks for an app we will build against Go, however my Rust POC is ridiculously slow and I'm sure it's because I don't fully understand the language yet. This runs in seconds in Go, but has been running for many minutes in Rust:

```
use serde_json::{Result, Value};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;

fn rule(data: Value) {
    for _i in 0..1000000000 {
        let ru = "589ea4b8-99d1-8d05-9358-4c172c10685b";
        let s = 0 as usize;

        let tl = data["tl"].as_array().unwrap().len();
        for i in s..tl {
            if data["tl"][i]["t"] == "my_value" && data["tl"][i]["refu"] == ru {
                //println!("  t {} matched with reference/ru {}\n", data["tl"][i]["t"], data["tl"][i]["refu"]);
                let el = data["el"].as_array().unwrap().len();
                for j in s..el {
                    if data["el"][j]["is_inpatient"] == true && data["el"][j]["eu"] == data["tl"][i]["eu"] {
                        //println!("  e {} matched.\n", data["el"][j]["eu"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn start() -> Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("../../data.json").expect("File should open read only");
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let v: Value = serde_json::from_reader(reader).expect("JSON was not well-formatted");
    //println!("Running rule");
    rule(v);
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let _r = start();
}
```

1) I know this is super ugly. It's just a speed POC so if it wins I plan to figure out the language in more detail later.

2) The big one: What am I doing wrong here that's causing Rust to perform so slowly?

Comment: 1. How did you compile this? 2. If your goal is speed, you probably shouldn't be looking-up the same items over and over again in the values. Use variables.

Comment: And specifically, use iteration rather than indexing.

Comment: Most likely the slowness is because you are not running in release mode. Here's an example of what the other comments are talking about: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c4660c2b32af364e2c6100492226017c

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I have rewritten the code to match the playground provided, that was a great help! One followup: If while going through the first for loop, I wanted to save the value of `tli["eu"]` so that I can move the second for loop outside of the first (to run after). How would I do that? I can't seem to figure out the variable scope.

Comment: I think I've done it right, here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a3f5173d5b6a0955baaac28cf372a132 However it's still slow. 4m38s vs the 34s of Go.

Comment: If you're testing performance, you should should be compiling with the --release flag. 
`cargo run --release`

Comment: As there isn't an example file to use, we can't actually measure the performance and give a proper answer. Provide a link to some data and that will help.

Answer (score 3):

1. Build with `--release` flag. Without it you get unoptimized build with debug checks, and this can be literally 100 times slower. Adding that flag is usually all you need to do to beat Go on execution speed, because Go doesn't have a heavy optimizer like this.
2. Rust doesn't do anything clever with caching of `[]` access, so every time you repeat `data["tl"]` it searches `data` for `"tl"`. It would be good to cache that search in a variable.
3. Loops in form `for i in 0..len {arr[i]}` are the slowest form of loop in Rust. It's faster to use iterators: `for item in arr {item}`. That's because `[i]` does an extra bounds check, and iterators don't have to. In your case that's probably a tiny issue, that's more relevant to heavy numeric code.